# Problem with the use of monomials: determine a formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Andrea has $x$ euros, Marco has $y$ euros more than Andrea but $z$ euros less than Luke. Determine the formula that expresses the total sum $s$ owned by the three friends.

Since Andrea has $x$ euros, Marco has $y$ euros more than Andrea and Luca has $z$ euros less than Marco, we can write the following equations:

1. The amount of money owned by Marco: $x + y $
2. The amount of money owned by Luke: $(x + y) - z $

The sum total, $s $, will be the sum of Andrew, Mark and Luke's money:

$$
s = x + (x + y) + ((x + y) - z)
$$
Simplifying this expression we get:

$$
s = x + x + y + x + y - z= 3x + 2y - z
$$

but the solution of the book is $s =  3x + 2y + z$. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marco has $s$ euros less than Luke, so Luke owns $(x+y)+z$, and not $(x+y)-z$. So that you will get the claimed result.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, sign errors happen to the best of us.